# PHP convert multiple strings with special chars as delimiters to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a multiple arrays with strings that comes out from a wordpress database.
Its a table from a plugin that stores the data in a very strange way, like this:

```
    print_r($results);
    
Array 
(
    [form] => text^name14^Antony~text^secondname14^White~email^email14^antony.white@gmail.com
)
Array  
(
    [form] => ......
)
```

I need to get the clean data, so:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {

    $formdata_array = explode('~',$result);
    $formdata_array_count = count($formdata_array);
    for ( $i=0 ; $i < $formdata_array_count ; $i++) {
       if ( empty( $formdata_array[$i] ) ) {
          continue;
       }
       $elemnts = explode('^',$formdata_array[$i]);

       $type = $elemnts[0];
       $element_name = $elemnts[1];
       $value = $elemnts[2];
       $value = nl2br($value);
}
```

And at this point  I get:

```
print_r($value)

    Antony 
    White
    antony.white@gmail.com
```

But I need to have an array to work with

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Antony
        [1] => White
        [2] => antony.white@gmail.com
    )
```

I triede differents methods like array_merge, array_column, array_combine but I can't get the final result

Comment: PLease show us your code, add a [mre].

Comment: My guess is that you call `print_r(array($output));` three times, for the three items. We need to see the code that does that to help you.

Comment: Are you [`explode()`ing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your input into `$output` properly to make the array?

Comment: Updated mi question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$results = [
   ['form' => "text^name14^Antony~text^secondname14^White~email^email14^antony.white@gmail.com"],
   ['form' => "text^name14^Georgy~text^secondname14^Black~email^email14^georgy.black@gmail.com"],
];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $output = [];
    $formdata_array = explode('~',$result['form']);
    $formdata_array_count = count($formdata_array);
    for ( $i=0 ; $i < $formdata_array_count ; $i++) {
       if ( empty( $formdata_array[$i] ) ) {
          continue;
       }
       $elements = explode('^',$formdata_array[$i]);

       $output[] = [
        'type' => $elements[0],
        'name' => $elements[1],
        'value' => $elements[2],
       ];
    }
   print_r(array_column($output, 'value'));
}
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Antony
    [1] => White
    [2] => antony.white@gmail.com
)
Array
(
    [0] => Georgy
    [1] => Black
    [2] => georgy.black@gmail.com
)
```

Comment: It works but with a strange behavior: the `1st` array it's ok, the 2nd is `1st + 2nd`, the 3rd is `1st + 2nd +3rd` and so on. You can try using multiple lines

Comment: That is not strange at all, that is because the `$output` has not been reset between loop runs. I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: My output from database is the one you see on top, multiple arrays, not an array vith multiple values

Comment: Please note that you really should be able to spot such things yourself. We are not here to implement a fully working solution, so to do you work for you. We are here to help you find _your_ solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It works. I got it. Thank you for your time

Comment: I made another change to mimic exactly the structure you get from the database.